# Can .js file "include" another .js file

Tags: javascript, include

In PhP you can.

In html, you sort of can with `<script src="...">` tag

but what about if we have a .js file and we want to include another .js file. How would we do so?

Comment: http://capmousse.github.io/include.js/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you mean in a browser context, not *directly*, but you can use a loader like at [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) (there are several).

Or to do it manually:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "/path/to/the/other/file.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].parentNode.appendChild(script);
```

Note, though,that with the above the functions and such in the other file won't be available for use right away. The code above *starts* the process of loading the file, but it continues asynchronously. You can use events to know that the load is complete (primarily the `load` event, but on older versions of IE you have to use `onreadystatechange` -- this is one reason people use loaders!).