# Sweetalert - Call function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm using SweetAlert.

http://tristanedwards.me/sweetalert

For this I need to initialize the plugin

```
<script src="lib/sweet-alert.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/sweet-alert.css">
```

I need to call the function `swal` from my file test.js, which is:

```
var accountnumber_c = $('#accountnumber_c').val();
if($('#accountnumber_c').val()=="")
{
    return;
}
swal('accountnumber_c');
```

This **works** in a php file but in test.js it gives "swal function is not defined".

Also how do I initialize the plugin in test.js?

Comment: Please create a [minimal complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we may diagnose your problem.

Comment: *"This works in a php file"* How exactly can a JS function "work" in a PHP file?

Comment: As per my understanding, you will have only one of the import statements (either sweet-alert.min.js or sweet-alert.js)

Comment: Please refer following older request
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16282909/can-js-file-include-another-js-file

Comment: @FelixKling may be he means file extension is .php but code is inside <script>.

Comment: Do: `<script src="lib/sweet-alert.min.js"></script>` first, then `<script src="pathToFile/test.js"></script>` second. That way sweet alert is loaded first, then `test.js` can access it.

Comment: Maybe read http://quirksmode.org/js/placejs.html ?

Answer (score -1):

As you want to refer swwtalert js in another js file you need to use following code to accomplish it:

```
 var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "/path/to/the/other/file.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].parentNode.appendChild(script);
    //for CSS file
    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="your/cssfilelocation/filename.css" type="text/css" />');
```

In case you need to include jquery before sweetalert, use similar code to add jquery before it.

Comment: @FelixKling He is not having any issue in php. his question is on how to reference another js (the js file he mentioned) in his custom js. To my understanding he is planning to move all js in on separate js file and refer that only in php file.
His question is "How do I initialize plugin in JS" as he wants to test js as complete unit.

Comment: That does not work
Uncaught ReferenceError: swal is not defined

Comment: This is the test.js


        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#accountnumber_c').blur(function(){
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = "swal/lib/sweet-alert.min.js";
        document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].parentNode.appendChild(script);
        swal(accountnumber_c);
});
});

Comment: @asvasdvasdvsadvs: That can't work because the file is not loaded yet when you call `swal`.

Comment: @asvasdvasdvsadvs the inclusion of sweet-alert.min,js should be the first thing in the test.js file. please do console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('script')) to verify if the js file is added.

Comment: @asvasdvasdvsadvs do you need jquery also before using sweetalert by any chance?

Comment: The problem was I had to load sweet-alert.min.js first.
However I am unable to load the css file.
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/sweet-alert.css">

Comment: That was my worry that css can create issue. you can load it as follows, as you are using jquery: $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="your/cssfilelocation/filename.css" type="text/css" />');

Comment: Yes I was able to insert the style-sheet with the above code.
Thank you

Comment: So can you accept my solution as answer as it solved your query :)